# How to update an AngularJS service based on uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

When the browser loads my webapp, the following constant is also loaded.

```
var v1_module = angular.module('v1_module', []);

v1_module.constant('v1_data', {
   params: [
      {
         name: "foo",
         items: [
            {
               name: "item 1",
               checked: false
            },
            {
               name: "item 2",
               checked: false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         name: "bar",
         items: [
            {
               name: "item 3",
               checked: false
            },
            {
               name: "item 4",
               checked: false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
});
```

The user can change it's value through a interface, let's say he changes the checked value of the first item to true using a checkbox, and then he must be able to save the content of `v1_data` to a .txt file. This .txt file can later be imported to the app in order to update `v1_data` and change the interface accordingly (in the example above, the check box of the first item must be checked). I realize that I shouldn't use a `constant`, because I can't change it's value. I've also tried to use `value` instead, but without success. Is it possible to accomplish this? Which service should I use? I'm getting the uploaded file and trying to update `v1_data` like the following. Is it wrong?

```
function getInputFile(files)
{    
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.readAsText(files[0]);

   reader.onload = function()
   {
      var input_file  = JSON.parse(reader.result);
      var v1_data     = input_file[0].data;

      v1_module.value('v1_data', v1_data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you've got going on here but you should be getting the file after the module is booted via service:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).service('getTextFile',function($q){
   this.getInputFile = function(files){
   var defer = $q.defer();  
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.readAsText(files[0]);

   reader.onload = function()
   {
      var input_file  = JSON.parse(reader.result);
      var v1_data     = input_file[0].data;

      defer.resolve(v1_data);
   }
   return defer.promise;
   }
}).run(function(getTextFile,$rootScope){
    getTextFile.getInputFile().then(function(file){
       $rootScope.file = file;
    });
});
```